Does scripture ever refer to anybody as an adherent of Hinduism or Sanatana Dharma?
They say that "Hindu" is a name given to Hindus by foreigners.  There are references to "Sanatana Dharma" in scripture - which would be the Hindu name of Hinduism.
While Hindus are ubiquitously referred to in scripture by their caste - are they ever referred to by their religion - say as "Sanatana Dharmis"?
